# Can functions in a 32 bit dll be called from a 64 bit dll using the `LoadLibrary` function?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, win32-process

Can functions in a 32 bit dll be called from a 64 bit dll using the `LoadLibrary` function?

Comment: Not at all. A DLL is either 32- or 64-bit, there are no 32- and 64-bit functions in the same DLL. They are incompatible and you will get an invalid executable error if you attempt to. 32-bit apps and dlls can only load 32-bit dlls - same goes for 64-bit.

Comment: There may be cases where a 32-bit DLL must be used in a 64-bit app (or the opposite). There is no straightforward implementation for this. But you can load the dll from an additional application and employ some sort of interprocess communication to implement a (custom) protocol for submitting requests and transferring data between the two.

Comment: What's the *problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please [edit] and tell us more about the _actual problem_ you're trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable This question could be mine.  We often need only a simple call to a  manufacturer 32bit dll function.  (hardware device) They are not able or willing deliver a 64bit dll version. How do you do that? Can we reverse engenieer an existing DLL to compile as 64bit dll?

Comment: @TomTom _"Can we reverse engenieer an existing DLL to compile as 64bit dll?"_ Good luck with that, I wouldn't recommend this. I'd rather do what the second comment suggests: make a 32 bit application that uses the 32 manufacturer supplied DLL and talk to that 32 bit application from your 64 but application though some sort of interprocess communication.

Comment: @tom The standard solution is to use an out-of-proc server and some sort of IPC. If you're willing to wrap the functionality of the 3rd-party module behind a COM interface, you pretty much get all the machinery required for free (launching of a COM surrogate process, and marshaling).

Comment: This article help you [Dealing with Legacy 32-bit 
Components in 64-bit 
Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20070322171317/http://www.64advantage.com/files/64-bit%20Insider%20Volume%201%20Issue%207.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it happens all the time when 32-bit processes are running on a 64-bit Windows. There's 64-bit ntdll.dll, which loads Wow64 layer DLLs and 32-bit ntdll.dll.

So it is hypothetically possible. If OS does this, you also should be able to do this.

In practice this may be not feasible without OS internals knowledge. Use a 32-bit process for that 32-bit DLL, and some sort of inter-process communication.